# Where to write new method of python. Either in existing .py files or I need to create a new one?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8

I am going to write a  method in point of sale containing  existing .py files. Should I create new python file ? or write new method in  existing .py files??

Comment: I recommend, you must write in separate file extending the module of point of sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add a new method to a particular model (e.g. sale.order), then inherit that particular model and add your method in a separate module i.e. custom module.

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit='sale.order'
    @api.multi
    def custom_test_method(self...)
```

Note:
This is in order to migrate to new version or update your code from github.  Mostly, any modification to your model needs to be done in a **custom module only.**

Answer (score 0):

Never change the code in the **base module** or the module's not written by you. Because when transition to update the latest code in order to get new functionalities or migration to another version, there is a plenty of chances for code loss and results to weird behaviour.

Use custom module for new method or overwriting the existing method
Eg: To add new method in pos module's, model "pos.order":

```
class pos_order(orm.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.order"

    def your_new_method(self, cr, uid, ids, args, context=None):
        ## your code
        return
```

For existing method:

```
class pos_order(orm.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.order"

    def your_existing_method(self, cr, uid, ids, args, context=None):
        res = super(pos_order, self).your_existing_method(cr, uid, ids, args, context=context)
        ## your code to change the existing method result
        return res
```